# Install ffmpeg in xampp and windows 7

Tags: ffmpeg, xampp

I am using xampp (1.7.7) and windows 7 (32bit) and PHP Version 5.3.8.

I do all steps copy php_ffmpeg.dll file in ext folder & Other files in system32 folder.

Add extenstion in php.ini file.

And restart the xampp.

But xampp not started. It shows error and then shut down.

Please Suggest me How to install ffmpeg on Xampp and windows 7.

Thanks & Regards
Sandeep Kawade

Comment: Can you edit your post with the error you have once xampp is starting?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution. This happened to me with the versions you're using as well. So, I am posting this solution, although its late lol.

Download this package: http://x32.elijst.nl/ffmpeg6-php53-win32-vc9-all.zip

Extract it and you'll see 7 dll files.... Copy php_ffmpeg.dll in xampp/php/ext

and the other 6 dll files in your windows system32 folder.. Restart Apache!

Enjoy!

Comment: seems it's depended to the exactly correct version. for example your file is for PHP 5.3
do you know how I should find it for PHP 5.5 ?

and also, do you know how I could install http://ffmpeg.org ?